# Can't advance beyond login screen with Chrome Remote Desktop in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, 18.04

Just downloaded and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I then installed Chrome Remote Desktop and Chrome 66, not Chromium.

I'm able to login to the machine remotely - when I type my user password, it takes the password but nothing happens. It doesn't reject the password, it just clears the field and does nothing. When I type in an incorrect password (just to see what it would do), it rejects it (which is what I would expect to happen).

I know Ubuntu switched back to X display manager for 18.04 - is there something else I need to configure?

Comment: Not really an answer, but here is a Google forum where multiple people complain of the same issue without any resolution. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2067278?hl=en  The only person that had any luck installed the remote desktop on Firefox instead of Chrome. Second to last post I think.